# Unable to understand why count is not getting incremented

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

As a part of exercise, i am writing a recursive code to count the number of nodes in a queue. The code part which I have added/modified (in NodeQueue.java) is here:

```
public class NodeQueue implements Queue
{
    static protected int count;                 //for RecNodeCount method only
    protected Node beingCountedNode = head;     //for RecNodeCount method only

// other methods..

public int RecNodeCount()
    {
        if(beingCountedNode == null)
            return count;
        else
        {
            count++;
            beingCountedNode = beingCountedNode.getNext();
            return RecNodeCount();
        }
    }
```

The entire code is as here:

Queue.java: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Dpkd8ynk

Node.java: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Zy0KbrtJ

NodeQueue.java: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j6hieiLG

SimpleQueue.java: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vaTy41z4

I am unable to understand why I am getting zero even after enqueueing few nodes in the queue. The `size` variable returns the correct number. I am doing more or less the same with the `count` variable (I think!) i.e. incrementing the required variable.

Comment: Linking to code not appearing in the question is usually a bad sign. If the code in the question is the only code relevant to the question you're asking, you should easily be able to narrow it down to a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which should easily fit into a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I believe the method will work (if `beingCountedNode` is set properly before the call. See @peter.petrov answer), it is weird to use instance variables as parameters for a function. I think the recursive function should have the signature `int Count( Node node )` which returns the number of nodes after (including) the given `Node.`

```
// returns the number of nodes in the list
public int Count(){ return CountHelper( head ); }

// helper recursive function
// returns the number of nodes in the list after and including "node".
// call with head of the list to get the count of all nodes.
private int CountHelper( Node node )
{
    if( node == null )
       return 0;
    else
       return 1 + CountHelper( node.getNext() );
}
```

Also note in your current example, you never reset `count`, so if I call `RecNodeCount()` twice in a row, your method will tell me the count is twice what it actually is. Edit, actually I guess it wouldn't since `beingCountedNode` would be null, but it is still weird to do it this way.

Comment: Works perfectly! Didn't realise that `beingCountedNode` is being set to null. Although I realised when @peter.petrov pointed it out. Even the resetting `count` part, agreed! :D Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is this following.

When this line is executed
`protected Node beingCountedNode = head;`

your `head` is null.

So `beingCountedNode` is set to null. Due to this,
later in your method you never enter the else clause.

Just add a few `System.out.println` calls in `RecNodeCount()`
and you'll see what exactly is happening in this method.

Comment: I think you are right. I added a line `System.out.println(beingCountedNode.getElement()+" ");` before `return count` in the if block and it returned `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at NodeQueue.RecNodeCount(NodeQueue.java:58)
        at SimpleQueue.main(SimpleQueue.java:34)`

Comment: @vipulnj yes, that means that `beingCountedNode` is null when you first call it. You probably want to set `beingCountedNode = head` in the constructor, not at declaration. The declaration and initialization is run before the constructor, when head is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not a direct answer for your issue, but why do you even use recursive and static variable here? Is' really easy to count nodes with simple while.

```
public int nodeCount(Node node) {
    int result = 0;
    while(node != null) {
        node = node.getNext();
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is an assignment to use recursion. 
"As a part of exercise, i am writing a recursive code"

Comment: Maybe, but it's always bad to use recursion, if you can do it iteratively.

Comment: anything done iteratively can be done recursively and vice versa. And it is not always bad, readability and maintainability are more important than execution speed/memory requirements a lot of the time.

Comment: Yeah, but I was trying to write a recursive code. Not an assignment given in school/college, just practicing.